# Is it possible to create a plugin built on top of Google Maps for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I currently am planning a small, but useful, addition to Google Maps for Android.  I was wondering if I could create a .apk file that, when installed, adds a feature to the stock Google Maps for Android.  The only thing I have found is [Google Add-on API](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html), although I don't think this is what I want.

If I use the above add-on API, I would be able to create a stand-alone application which fully implements Google Maps API... right?  Please give me some clarity here, and let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Add-on API is a set of classes that allow you to show google maps inside your application. Most apps use this for simply showing a map with some sort of marker on it.

The out of the box functionality is fairly limited and not nearly as feature rich as the google maps application. With enough time and effort you could possibly build a replacement for google maps but it's not as simple as just adding on functionality.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) for a guide on how to get started using the APIs.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought I had to do.  But there is no way to add an actual plugin to Google Maps?  So I have all the same functionality but one extra feature.

Comment: I don't think there is any concept of a plugin that adds functionality to an app. I think this would be a security issue.

Answer (score 3):

It now is possible to create plugins for google maps or any other app provided you have root access for your android device. once you have the root access, you can use the [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401) created by one of the XDA recognised developer [rovo89](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4419114)

Please note that this will be only available for the rooted devices that have this framework installed. Again this is an indirect way to enhance any application deployed on your device provided you have an idea of which methods you need to hook into. in the same thread mentioned there is also a [link](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial) to toutorial which explains how to use the xposed framework to modify and create your own mods.

For non rooted devices, unfortunately, there is no way to implement this functionality.